# ubuntu 14.04 completely dead

Tags: 14.04

After having issues with crashing due to graphics drivers issues. My new install freezes after login. If I try to recover using the USB I installed it with it boots up to the login screen with the screen not working. (get login prompt sound, but no screen)

How do I recover?

Comment: Can you get to tty?

Comment: To get to a tty, you can use the keyboard short cut 'Ctrl'+'Alt'+'F1'. If you can, please add what graphics card and drivers you are using (you can get those by running `lspci -v`), and what computer make/model you are using.

Comment: Only if I boot using usb. I would just prefer to reinstall ubuntu but don't even get the option to do that. Lspci o/p shows Intel Corp 2nd generation core processor family integrated graphics controller. Also 3d controller nvidia gf119 (GeForce gt 520mx)

Comment: I'm having this issue. After trawling various forums it seems to be related to the graphics card drivers. I've tried all the nvidia drivers installed 331.38, 304.117 & get the scrambled screen on 1/4 of the screen & it crashes within 10 minutes. The default x.org nouveau appeared to be more stable, but ran the fans constantly resulting in poor battery (the main reason for upgrading).

Update, the x.org nouveau now doesn't bring up the screen. Completely blank.

Comment: Should have added using Samsung NP300V, Intel i5, with 8G of RAM

Comment: I had to use nvidia-304. Otherwise, whenever firefox starts, the screen goes spaghetti with the nouveau driver. Even if your CPU is 64 bit, it looks like that's an X86 video card, so if you are trying to use the 64 bit ubuntu, you need to switch to the i386 version instead.